# How can I retrieve 3 values ​with the every id in the foreach method?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

```
   @foreach ($options as $ozellik)
                        @if($ozellik->urun_kategori == $urunler->id )

                        <tr>
                            <td> <b> {!!$ozellik->ozellik!!}</b></td>
                            <td>{!!$ozellik->aciklama!!}</td>
                        </tr>

   @endif
   @endforeach
```

this is my blade

I want to retrieve 3 values for every id. How can i do that. It has to retrieve 3 values for each id.

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYdxX.png)

For example i want to get 3 of the values for "urun_kategori" = 7

But there are 4 records for "urun_kategori" = 7

[This is where is set $options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyx4l.png)

Comment: This is not the right place to implement this logic ... can you please show the code where u retrive the ```$options``` array/collection in the controller?

Comment: i didnt use controller i just got the datas with foreach loop

Comment: Just show where ever u set ```$options```

Comment: I just set $options in web.php. I edited the post you can look the picture.

Comment: That is not very helpful. First of all, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and second, show us what the variable actually _contains_, instead of the code that fills or sets it.

Comment: $options contains "options" table in the database. I retrieve all  "options" table values from web.php. I am not using controller, thats what i have. web.php->blade->foreach that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to test it since you did not provide a sample dataset. The solution to your problem should look something like this:

```php
$options = $options->groupBy('urun_kategori')
    ->flatMap(function($group) {
      return $group->take(3);
    });
```

... place that inside your `web.php` after the line `$options = App\Option::all();`

Explanation:
`groupBy` as the name suggest groups the collection by the given attribute 'urun_kategori' into subcollections. In the `flatMap` we limit the the amount of items in each group to 3 - `take(3)`, then flatten the array because we dont need the subcollections anymore.